# "no input file specified" with php7-fpm on nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, php-7, fpm

I am new to nginx and installing phpmyadmin on it. I'm on a Debian stretch distro. The `no input file specified` error I'm getting when trying to visit `/phpmyadmin` comes up over and over on StackOverflow but they all seem to be older posts. Trying to piece together the proper config from many different suggestions on the web has been a nightmare. I tried some of the solutions mentioned but none worked for me. Here's my complete config file:

```
server {
  gzip on;
  gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/javascript;

  root /home/me/projects/MyApp/public;
  location / {
      try_files $uri @proxy;
      expires max;
  }
  location @proxy {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;

  }

  location /phpmyadmin {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html;
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is contained in `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`? You probably need to add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;`

Comment: Ah, I just figured that was some standard file and didn't bother to look. There is no file with that name. I replaced that line in the config file with your suggestion. I'm getting a blank page now. But I'm closer. Thanks!

Comment: You may find a file called `fastcgi_params` which contains a number of `fastcgi_param` definitions necessary to PHP.

Comment: Yeah, just found it a few minutes ago in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params. I included that in my config. Now I am getting a blank web page that says only "Access denied."

Comment: Ugh, switched the `cgi.fix_pathinfo` setting back to the default in php.ini and now getting "File not found" message on webpage. I'm really missing apt-get right about now.

Comment: OK, so I can now pull it up if I type in index.php directly. Very close now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is the section of my config file that at least works (I can't guarantee it is secure) with phpmyadmin:

```
  location /phpmyadmin/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~* \.php$ {
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
      }
    }
```

I also had to comment out a line in my php.ini file that I had uncommented out per a suggestion of some online tutorial:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

to

```
;cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

Comment: Definitely correct and valid with Ubuntu 17.10 and PHP7.0

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1 from me